# Intellij shortcut to convert code to upper or lower case?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the Intellij shortcut to convert code to upper or lower case?

Answer (score 552, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

Or <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> if you are using Mac OSX.

In the future, hit the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> shortcut key and search for the action that you are after. In this case, search for: *Toggle Case*.

Comment: In case it helps someone who wanders in here: In Eclipse, this is CMD+SHFT+Y (lower) and CMD+SHIFT+X (upper)

Comment: I have trouble where sometimes pressing CTRL+SHIFT+U just replaces the selected text with the letter U.... sometimes it works, but usually it just does the replacing.

Comment: @Trenton  - if you're using Ubuntu CTRL+SHIFT+U by default is used for Unicode input thus you're seeing the letter u. If you don't use it you should probably unbind it (looks like it's not so easy http://askubuntu.com/questions/367646/is-it-possible-to-unbind-or-change-the-unicode-input-global-shortcut) or define a new shortcut for this action in Intellijf

Comment: `export XMODIFIERS="" ./bin/idea.sh` solves to me, using Ubuntu.

Comment: @Kuba in October 2018 I can confirm that Debian does this too

Answer (score 47):

According to the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/basic-editing.html) :

> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> : Toggle case of the
>   selected text block

Comment: Obsolete, do not toggle any more. It will only make characters upper case.

Answer (score 30):

I would **highly** recommend ***[String Manipulation plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/2162-string-manipulation)*** for Intellij.

With a simple <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> (<kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> for *Mac*) you get:

[image]

So you can easily manipulate with strings in the following way:

[image]

Answer (score 27):

If you are an Ubuntu User you will notice that `Ctrl + Shift + U` will add an **u** instead of toggling the case.

The solution for me was to change the KeyMap from:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>  --> <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>

You can do so with this [Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)

Comment: There's an alternative way, supressing `Ctrl + Shift + U` handling by Ubuntu, so IntelliJ Idea works as usual
https://superuser.com/questions/358749/how-to-disable-ctrlshiftu

Answer (score 4):

Select the text/word/line to be modified and hitting <kbd>Cntrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>` (MAC) works. Please look [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/toggling-case.html) for more detail

Comment: Any specific reason it is down voted? I just verified in IntelliJ and confirmed this

Comment: Had to convert a project from MSSQL (Pascal case) to Postgres (lowercase).  This saved me a ton of time!

Answer (score 4):

Please check your hot-key settings first. You could go to

> File > Settings > Search for Keymap > Search for Toggle Case

and see what hot-key has been configured. See screenshot below:-

[image]

If not configured, create a new one for yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Toggle case in **Intellij** IDE:

For **Ubuntu** OS use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>

For **Windows** OS use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>